# Samsung Galaxy core 2 is okay in Windows 8.1 but cannot see in Android 64 bit studio

Tags: android-studio

Android 64 bit on Windows cannot see my phone that is installed correctly in Windows 8.1.

I have read some of the articles about setting up a Samsung or other phone to work as an Android Device, but I cannot find my problem. I installed the Samsung Galaxy Core 2 on Windows 8.1. It looks fine from Windows Device Manager. It shows up as a working device Galaxy Core 2. I tried to update the driver, but I have the latest. I then installed the Kies3 Samsung software in case something was wrong with the Windows setup for the phone, but it seems okay. I can view the contents of the phone from Windows with the Kies3 software. I was also able to borrow another Android phone from a friend and my studio would see it. I just bought this phone tonight to do development, and now it does not work.

When I run my Android project, I get the option to "Chose a Running Device". My Samsung phone does not show up. I looked at the article "ADB not recognizing Samsung Galaxy S5" for Windows 7. This article says I should have another device in my Windows Device Manager named Android Phone.

I am running the lastest version of Android Studio 64. I have the Oct. 23 build of Studio which is the latest. Please help me find out why Studio cannot see my phone.

I tried rebooting the phone to get Windows to install the ADB driver, but the phone still cannot be seen by Windows 8.1 professional.

Thanks...

Comment: check if developer mode enabled, signature accepted, phone's ADB(modem) drivers are installed (usually you get this driver prompted when you boot your phone into bootloader)

Comment: Are you talking about "developer mode being enabled" on the phone? I thought that Studio should pick it up if Windows can see it. Do you know if there is a setting to tell Studio to check for new hardware? thanks..

Comment: windows not always installs the ADB modem driver. it installs the usb driver to recognize your phone and to read your USB stuffs. boot your phone into bootloader windows will then definitely ask you to install the required adb modem driver. once the driver is installed A.Studio will find your device

Comment: I just bought the phone today, and it has a 1 year warranty. From what I read if I unlock the bootloader then the phone warranty is voided on my new phone. Is there not just a way to install the ABD driver or tell Studio that I have this phone? thanks again

Comment: you don't need to reflash the phone, just switch off the phone, press volume key down + power it will confirm whether to enter into download mode. press volume up and confirm. at this point windows will prompt for the correct ADB modem driver for your device @jabo

Comment: Thanks the phone says it is downloading...

Comment: now windows will install or identify  your adb drivers, insall them restart your phone and AStudio will find your device

Comment: How long will this take? I thought it would be a few seconds. The screen says "Downloading Do not turn off target!!". This is my first Android phone.

Comment: hahaha... it won't download anything. it is in "downloading mode" where it waits any command from ADB. did windows find any drivers? Just turn off and on :) sorry i should have mentioned this earlier.

Comment: I ended up powering off after nothing happened, this time I am asked to "apply update from ADB".

Comment: Messages now are:"applied the CSC-code: TGY Successfully applied multi-csc. Now send the package you want to apply to the device with the "abd sideload <filename>...

Comment: no windows did not install any new drivers. Still the same problem Studio cannot see it.

Comment: Is the developer menu enabled on your phone and do you have "USB Debugging" enabled in there? Studio will only see the phone if that is the case. The phone should also display some "usb debug mode" icon once you plug it into the computer. that is afaik even independent from windows detecting it correctly.

Comment: You are a genius. That was all I had to do. I went to Settings - About Phone - Built Number. I tapped it about 6 times, and went into Developer Mode. I then set the option USB Debug mode.

Comment: The link: http://androidxda.com/root-samsung-galaxy-core-duos-gt-i8262d was helpful in solving this. Thanks!!